# Can't find variable $ - works on desktop and Androids but not iOS

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

jQuery DateTimePicker is working fine on all devices except iOS. On iOS it doesn't even load. In the console.log for iOS it says:

> Can't find variable $

However this doesn't show in the console.log for other devices. Is there any reason why it would be causing that issue? Is the jQuery being loaded incorrectly?

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css />
<script src=https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.css>
<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.js></script>

<script src=https://cdn.tailwindcss.com></script>
<!--modified 27/07/22 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/tailwind.css" />

<!-- main css and responsive css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/jquery.datetimepickerresponsive.min.css" media="screen and (max-width: 767px)" />

<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js integrity="sha512-AIOTidJAcHBH2G/oZv9viEGXRqDNmfdPVPYOYKGy3fti0xIplnlgMHUGfuNRzC6FkzIo0iIxgFnr9RikFxK+sw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Does this need to be changed?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Comment: why would that work ? isn't this '$' the issue?

Comment: Apologies, you're right. Removed the comment. 
Is your application js being included in the head with jquery or in the body?

Answer (score 0):

You may try loading jQuery from a different CDN.
In my case the problem appears only when using a certain provider. Maybe internal phone cache issue, can't tell.